# What is the exact procedure used for accepting payments through GreenMoney API?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have been trying to the greenMoney platform's API to accept the payments.
But I always Get client Id not found. Trying all id's given and none of them matched.
Can someone please guide further.

Here is the example that I have implemented.
https://github.com/d-bott/Green-PHP-SDK/blob/master/examples/singleBillpay.php

I did use Id and password received in email while creating a new client on GreenMoney.

As every time I hit the API and the response I get is:
Check not created.
Error Code: 1
Error: Client_ID NOT in Database.

What is the "Client_ID" and "ApiPassword" to be used ?

Comment: Are you asking for help with some specific issue in your code or for a generic lecture about the payment service?

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question right now because your question doesn't include any code, or an example of the desired behavior and the actual behavior. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you are running the example as-is, the problem is here: `$ClientID = "your_client_id";`. You're supposed to customise that.

Comment: I did replace client Id and password, with the one I received in email from GreenMoney.